# How to create drop menu from every li?

Tags: css

I have a problem with dropmenu. I created dropmenu from li:YOU and I want to create dropmenu from li: VIEW and HELP, but every dropmenu is below YOU. I don't know what I should to do that every dropmenu was below YOU, VIEW and HELP. I tried many ways but everything failed. And I have ask, I want to pubblish my question but show information that I have to add more detail.

```css
*{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 box-sizing:border-box;
}

body {
 text-align: center;
 background: #e0e0e0;
 padding-bottom: 200px;
}


nav{
 height:100px;
 display:flex;
 font-size:15px;
 align-items:center;
 justify-content:center;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 background-color:blue;
 width:100%;
 position:relative;

 
}



nav ul{
 display:flex;
 
}

nav ul li{
 list-style:none;
}


nav ul li a{
 text-decoration:none;
 color:black;
 position:relative;
 letter-spacing:2px;
 padding:20px 20px;
 margin:20px 0;
 font-weight:bold;
 background-color:green;
 
}



.dropOut .triangle{
 width:0;
 height:0;
 position:absolute;
 border-left: 8px solid transparent;
 border-right: 8px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 8px solid red;
 top: -8px;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -8px;
}

.dropdownContain{
 width:160px;
 position:absolute;
 margin-top:20px;
 left:50%;
 margin-left: -80px;
}



.dropOut{
 width:160px;
 background-color:yellow;
 position:relative;
    opacity:0;


 
 
}

.dropOut ul {
 text-align:center;
 padding: 10px 0;
 display:block;
 
}
.dropOut ul li {
 text-align: center;
    width:160px;
 padding: 12px 0 10px 0;
 margin: 0px ;
 color: red;
}

.dropOut ul li:hover {
 background: #0D74FB;
}

nav ul li a:hover{
 color:white;
}

ul li:hover a { color: white; }
ul li:hover .dropdownContain { top: 65px; }
ul li:hover .underline { border-bottom-color: #777; }
ul li:hover .dropOut { opacity: 1; margin-top: 8px; }
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">View</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">You</a>
    <div class="dropdownContain">
    <div class="dropOut">
    <div class="triangle"></div>
      <ul>
        <li>Plan</li>
     <li>Gallery</li>
     <li>Contact</li>
     <li>f1</li>
     </ul>
     </div>
     </div>
     </li>
   <li><a href="#">Help</a> <div class="dropdownContain1">
    <div class="dropOut">
    <div class="tringle"></div>
      <ul>
        <li>Plan</li>
     <li>Service</li>
     <li>Contact</li>
     <li>gallery</li>
     </ul>
     </div>
     </div>
     </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: You have a nmber of unclosed/extra divs there...I suggest you validate your HTML.

Comment: Where I have unclosed div, I validate now and everything is OK

Comment: i see a class `dropdownContain1` but it doesn't exist in the css? is this were your problem starts?

Comment: I tryed to do with class dropdownContain dropmenu below every li, but everything was below li:YOU, so I create class cropdownContain1 that this dropmenu was below li:HELP, but I don't know how this class style

Comment: You need to add `position:relative` to the parent `li`